# Deleting Strings from text file Android - File IO

Tags: android, file-io

I would like to delete a string from a text file. I have seen that I need a temp file to do this with.  I would like to read from a list.txt file and delete a string in it.  The file I wish to search through has already been created and populated  I have seen other posts on this and am trying to modify it to my own personal project.  Currently I have:

```
        package com.nullwall.listmanager;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

public class IPR3Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        DoWork("TestString");
    }


public void DoWork(String deleteFromFile)
{
    try{
    String delete = deleteFromFile;
    String line;

    //locates a new file named list.txt
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"projects");
    File file = new File(root, "list.txt");

    //creates buffers
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()));
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    //Loads list.txt into bufferedReader, deletes line and moves on
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.equals(deleteFromFile))
        {
        line.replace(deleteFromFile, "");
        stringBuffer.append("\n");      
        }
        else 
        {
        stringBuffer.append(line);
        stringBuffer.append("\n");
        }
    }
    //Entire file has now been loaded into memory

    //creates new Filewriter, append to false, rewrites list.txt with stringBuffer minus string
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, false);
    writer.write(stringBuffer.toString());
    System.out.println("file written");

    //closes writer
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();


    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }

}


}
```

I have list.txt with random strings like this :

```
notstring
notstring
notstring
teststring 
notstring 
notstring
```

After running, nothing happens.  I am fairly new to doing File IO like this so please don't overlook simple things I may have missed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try storing file into a String buffer replace what you intend to replace, then replace the contents of the file entirely. Also another thing is File IO is not necessarily the same in android. Since android uses context the approach to file IO is different. Check the dev site for more info on file IO from android.

Comment: edited my post with your suggestions...still nothing has been edited.  Am I writing the code correctly?  I added comments with my thought process.